# Cannot Read $scope in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write something with [Angular Bootstrap's Modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal). This injects a div at the end of the html body, which is not wrapped in a controller. The result is I have not been able to access bindings via $scope, but for some reason I can write them to the view from the model.

```
The code can be found here.
```

[Link to code on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lG8LGXYdz0S6CiBNOARS?p=preview)

On line 23, you will find the $scope is successfully written to, and the data is bound to a input. However, if you then edit the input, 3 seconds later, the $scope that is bound to it is alerted, but changes in the view are not reflected. I have found that this can be solved by wrapping the modal in its own controller, but then I am unable to get what I want to do to work.

Is it possible to access changed in the model from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, but do not understand the issue, so would be grateful if someone could explain.

The code needs to be change to:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.yn = 'this';
alert( $scope.data.yn );
setTimeout( function(){alert( $scope.data.yn )}, 3000 );
```

and the input to:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" value="David" data-ng-model="data.yn" />
```

From:

```
$scope = {};
$scope.yn = 'this';
alert( $scope.yn );
setTimeout( function(){alert( $scope.yn )}, 3000 );
```

input:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" value="David" data-ng-model="yn" />
```

Comment: Models should always have dots in them. The reason has been detailed many times by people who could describe it much better than me. Here is one example: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Answer (score 1):

Per the angular [wiki page](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) on scope best practices.

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. (See this example for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit easier to get my head round.

Comment: @KohjahBreese great that you got it working and it makes sense, could you mark either of the answers as correct? Picky about unanswered questions ;)

Comment: I would, but I am unable to select my own answer for another 41 minutes.